# Problem with PDE boundary and initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, boundary-conditions

I am trying to numerically solve the following PDE

```
pde = 
  With[{d = .25, \[Rho] = .5, M = 10, T = 2, 
    L = 10, \[Alpha] = 0.2},
   {
    D[n[x, t], {t, 1}] ==
     Piecewise[
       Table[{(1 - x^2/(3 d (M T - i T)))* 
          n[x, t]* g / Sqrt[3 d (M T - i T)] , 
         i T < t < i T + \[Alpha] T && -\[Sqrt](3 d*(M T - i T)) < 
           x < \[Sqrt](3 d*(M T - i T)) }, {i, 0, M - 1}]
       ]
      +
      Piecewise[
       Table[{d * D[n[x, t], {x, 2}] - \[Rho] * n[x, t], 
         i T + \[Alpha] T < t < (i + 1) T}, {i, 0, M - 1}]
       ],
    n[x, 0] == InitialCondition,
    (D[n[x, t], x] /. x -> -L) == (D[n[x, t], x] /. x -> L) == 0
    }
   ];
```

However, when I try to get the solution through

```
sln = With[{M = 10, L=10},
   ParametricNDSolveValue[
   pde /. InitialCondition -> 0.5  (*uniform*),
   n, {x, -L, L}, {t, 0, M T}, {g},
   AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
  ];
```

and then write, for example, `sln[.5][0,5]`, MMA v13.2 gives an error `NDSolve::ibcinc` stating the initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent, but it also produces a result. Could someone help me figure out what's happening?

I want to keep `g` as a parameter to then be able to manipulate the plots by varying it, say

`Manipulate[Plot[{sln[g][0, t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All],{g, 0.1, 10}]`

However, in that case MMA throws out the error and then stops the evaluation.

PS: The reason I have added `PrecisionGoal` is that without it, at longer times the solution seems to have a lot of numerical error. For example, after removing `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, MMA solves the pde with no error, but when I look at
`Plot[{sln[.1][x, 14]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]`, the plot does not make sense to me.

Comment: PS2: I realized with only ```PrecisionGoal``` there is no error, but the final results/plots don't make sense. However I got things to work with ```AccuracyGoal -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 10```. This seems like an accident, since with a different initial condition ```n[x,0] = Sin[ Pi x /(2L)]^2``` the error persists even with these accuracy and precision goals.

Comment: @AlexTrounev the Neumann boundary condition is on the derivative of the function, not its value

Comment: What do you try to solve? It looks like delay equation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's a reaction-diffusion system, where at specified time intervals there is particle creation (the first piecewise), and in other intervals there is diffusion and particle annihilation

Comment: Thank you, please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using Mathematica FEM as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

{d = .25, \[Rho] = .5, M = 10, T = 2, L = 10, \[Alpha] = 0.2}; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[-L <= x <= L, {x}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 1/100];
pde = {D[n[x, t], {t, 1}] == (f1[t, x, g] + f3[t]) n[x, t] + 
     f2[t] D[n[x, t], x, x], n[x, 0] == InitialCondition};

f1[t_, x_, g_] := 
 g Piecewise[
   Table[{(1 - x^2/(3 d (M T - i T)))/Sqrt[3 d (M T - i T)], 
     i T < t < i T + \[Alpha] T && -\[Sqrt](3 d*(M T - i T)) < 
       x < \[Sqrt](3 d*(M T - i T))}, {i, 0, M - 1}]]; 
f2[t_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{d, i T + \[Alpha] T < t < (i + 1) T}, {i, 0, M - 1}]]; 
f3[t_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{-\[Rho], i T + \[Alpha] T < t < (i + 1) T}, {i, 0, M - 1}]];
sol = NDSolveValue[pde /. {InitialCondition -> .5, g -> .5}, 
  n, {t, 0, M T}, {x} \[Element] mesh];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[sol[x, t], {t, 0, T}, {x, -L, L}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[sol[x, t], {t, 0, M T}, {x, -L, L}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.**
In a case of initial condition in a form of `n[x,0] = Sin[ Pi x /(2L)]^2` we also have numerical solution without errors. It looks like this one
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Do we not need to specify boundary conditions?

Comment: @SaMaSo In a case of Mathematica FEM when using `(D[n[x, t], x] /. x -> -L) == (D[n[x, t], x] /. x -> L) == 0` there is automatic `NeumannValue[0, True] ` applied. So you don't need to take into account these boundary conditions.

Comment: Ok thank you. Just to make sure I understand correctly, with FEM I would only need to specify the BC if they are Dirichlet or mixed, or otherwise Neumann is automatically enforced. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are right, `NeumannValue[0, True]` is automatically enforced.